# Display Dashboards Externally on TV

Tags: api, dashboard

I've been investigating for a secure, but simple way to display Salesforce dashboards on an external monitor/TV.

What I want to do is be able to display opportunities, and also cases, on a large screen - mainly for managers to see a live status.

I was thinking of just hooking up a separate SalesForce login, with a custom profile that only has read access to the reports and dashboard, and the objects/fields it needs - but I feel uncomfortable having a user account with access to a production Salesforce instance running on a remote machine (though it will be on our secure LAN).

I have looked at some third party tools like Geckoboard, but wanted to avoid additional costs.

I was thinking of using the API, and authenticating via OAuth, and pulling the data out, but was stuck with thinking about what tools to use to present the data?

What have others used in the past? Am I being over cautious with security?

Comment: It sounds like you're agnostic as to the visual presentation (i.e., showing the actual Salesforce dashboard versus some other representation of the same underlying data). Is that accurate?

Comment: Does not have to be a SF Dashboard, deep down it just needs to be some Salesforce data displayed in a pretty format.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a user with read only access is the best mechanism available to do this.  You can add IP range restrictions on the profile to limit access specifically to your corporate network which will prevent those from outside the organization accessing the data. 
[IP range restriction information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_loginrestrict.htm&type=5)

Keep in mind that dashboard data is aggregated via the running user and the user that you have on the remote machine could in theory be at the bottom of the hierarchy and would, therefore, have no ability to see the underlying report records or the records themselves.